# How to detect if Facebook app is installed on iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, url-scheme

On iOS, you can launch the Facebook app and link to a profile by opening a url like this: fb://profile/12345

The only problem is that if the Facebook app isn't installed, nothing happens.

Is there a way to detect if the app is installed or if the url scheme fb:// is supported?

This would apply broadly to other apps like Twitter as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643522/fbsdksharedialog-of-facebook-sdk-is-not-working-on-ios9/39159507#39159507

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
BOOL isInstalled = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]]

if (isInstalled) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: You also need to include LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key into info.plist for iOS 9 with value "fb".

Answer (score 7):

Try just using the `canOpenURL:` function

```
NSURL *fbURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"];//or whatever url you're checking

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:fbURL])
{
  //open it etc  
}
```

Comment: Don't encourage duplicate questions.

Comment: I wrote it before I saw the closure votes. Good call, I'll vote as well