# FBSDKShareDialog of Facebook SDK is not working on iOS9?

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.x

With Xcode7, I upgrade Facebook SDK to pod FBSDKShareKit (4.6.0). And I have added Facebook scheme to WhiteList as below. 
reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

However, the following code only show iOS default social dialog on iOS9. The same code with the same binary on iOS8 can open Facebook app and show the Sharing Dialog properly.

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com"]];
content.contentDescription = @"Test";
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:nil];
```

I guess Facebook app is not found on iOS9 and then show the default social dialog. Even no error message showed.

Do I miss anything? Or, it's an iOS9 bug?

Comment: I got the same problem. I think I followed everything on the doc. If Facebook app is not found it should still use the web form of sharing. And it works fine in simulator.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm guessing Facebook changed the behaviour because iOS 9 now pops up a dialog asking if you would like to "Open Facebook?" when doing app-switching. Even for FBSDKLoginManager, the app-switching (native) method seems to be less preferred than a modal UIWebView.

However, you can still force the share dialog to switch to the Facebook app (assuming you have your application plist setup as described in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) by using this method:

```
FBSDKShareDialog *dialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fbauth2://"]]){
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeNative;
}
else {
    dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser; //or FBSDKShareDialogModeAutomatic
}
dialog.shareContent = content;
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.fromViewController = self;
[dialog show];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works, and this is what I want.^^

Comment: In addition, this won't work if the fb app is not installed so you'd better check it and if it's not installed, use FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser instead.

Comment: @mrhangz I have edited the solution to include a check if the Facebook App is installed. I was assuming it would automatically fallback to other modes, but it doesn't. Thanks! Also, I prefer the FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser over FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser.

Comment: To me it seems like a facebook sdk bug. I couldn't use anything except FBSDKShareDialogModeFeedBrowser (not even automatic), if it works for you it's great :)

Comment: Be careful with this solution, because from 4.1 there are significant changes about exception list for iOS9.

Comment: yeah none of these fallback modes work on iOS9 if the Facebook app isn't installed

Comment: Just tested on iOS 11. `dialog.mode = FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser` is what I needed to do if the Facebook app isn't installed, otherwise it wouldn't show anything. 

Comment: Is it possible to share photo to facebook using FBSDKShareKit without having native facebook app?  I tried with below code
 `let share_dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
                        share_dialog.mode = .browser
                        share_dialog.delegate = self
                        share_dialog.fromViewController = self
                         share_dialog.shareContent = content
                         share_dialog.show()`

Its not working.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 9 below is the only solution that worked for me to detect if facebook app is installed in the device or not:

```
 NSString *urlString = @"fbapi://";
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url1]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url1];
    }
    else {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itunes link for download app"]];
    }
```